# Are relational database packages and their relevent derivatives of SQL IDE'S SDK'S or just implementations of Collection structures?

Tags: database

This question is purely for reasons of curiosity.

where do DBMS's like Oracle and SQL server sit on the heirarchy of 'programming languages'?

I imagine it would be possible to program an app using (for example) c# collection classes that would act similar to DBMS's.

But is this the way that DBMS's work or do they directly access system resources in the same way that higher level programming languages do?

**Edit**
Or more simply put, is Oracle more equivalent to .net or microsoft office?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "database package"?

Comment: well, the big ones like oracle, SQL Server etc maybe Access.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean with "package"? Oracle as packages, but I'm not aware of any other DBMS that supports that (certainly not SQL Server)

Comment: OK, simplified. Is SQL a language in it's own right or is it a software managed interface between DBMS and a language that the DBMS may be prgrammed in?

Comment: I've eliminated the word packages in my question.

Comment: Removed the C# tag, as this question really has nothing at all to do with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical client-server DBMS is not just a single language, but a combination of several languages and technologies that work together, including (but not limited to):

- Server:

  - Physical storage - typically OS files or even raw partitions on top of which are DBMS processes and threads.
  - Data model - tables, indexes, constraints etc.
  - A language for describing the data model - typically Data Definition Language (DDL) SQL.
  - Query language - typically Data Manipulation Language (DML) SQL.
  - Procedural SQL extensions for writing triggers and stored procedures, such as PL/SQL in Oracle or Transact-SQL in MS SQL Server.
  - Managed language such as Java or C# that executes "within" DBMS and can also be used to implement triggers and stored procedures.
- Client:

  - Various administrative tools, typically both command-line and GUI.
  - Drivers and APIs enabling access to database from general-purpose languages. This includes DBMS-independent APIs such as ODBC, OLEDB, ADO.NET, JDBC, BDE etc... as well as DBMS-specific APIs such as Oracle's OCI.
  - On top of all that sit client applications that actually implement some useful functionality, written in these general-purpose languages. There are all kinds of clients, from "classic" to multi-tier, but this is another topic...

There are also much simpler "embedded" DBMSes, intended to be used as a local "private" storage for specific application, not in client-server environment.

Most DBMSes are "relational" but there are also "object-oriented" and "No SQL" / "key-value store" systems and all kinds of hybrids thereof.

**So, could you implement a DBMS in "normal" language such as Java or C#?**

Theoretically, yes. Practically, no!

Enabling clients to access data **concurrently, safely and quickly** is a hard problem that DBMSes solve. Viewing a database as a set of tables is deceptively simple - there is a ton of complexity that allows the DBMS to maintain this illusion of (relative) simplicity.

Just as you won't use assembler in most situations because higher-level language implements concepts that allow you to be productive, and just as you won't implement your own data structures and algorithms if appropriate libraries are already available, you also won't try to manage your data if there is a DBMS available that covers your needs.

Comment: So, does a DBMS have more in common with a language framework like .net or JAVA, or a productivity suite that UTILISES languages to encode it's applications OR a library such as JQUERY that extends a language?

Comment: Sorry if Im being tiresome on this, I don't think at this stage in my career I have the appropriate vocabulary to efficiantly ask exactly what I want to know.

Comment: @DylanJackson It has commonality with all, yet it is in category of its own. In one sense, it is a development tool, yet is is also a software package in its own right that needs to be installed and often administered as a separate unit.

Answer (score 0):

SQL - Structured Query Language is indeed a language used to manage data in a relational database managed system.
SQL Server, Oracle and Access are relational database management systems that use Structured Query Language as a way of programatically accessing and updtinding/inserting data.

So to answer your question "where do DBMS's like Oracle and SQL server sit on the heirachy of 'programming languages'?", DBMS's aren't programming languages they are relational database management systems, but SQL is a language. Those DBMS systems would likely store and manage data in a highly optimized and proprietary way, but they all provide a common 'interface' -SQL in this case as a method of access.

DBMS is the software, SQL is a langauge.  I think you might be confusing the two.

Comment: I absolutely understand the difference between  DBMS and SQL. I think because of my inexperience in the industry i'm misrepresenting my question. I think Im asking is the actual SOFTWARE an SDK/IDE equivalent (given that it does have it's own language) OR is it JUST anothe SOFTWARE package with a 'pseudo language' as it's interface.

Comment: Or more simply put, is Oracle more equivalent to .net or microsoft office?

Comment: @DylanJackson A typical client-server DBMS (such as Oracle) is neither. It is really in a category of its own. It has both "software" components - actual processes that run under OS (or sometimes even without OS!) as well as "API" or "SDK" components that are "consumed" by general-purpose languages to implement the actual useful functionality on top of the DBMS.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic so, the underlying 'structure' that holds the data and applies the logic to queries etc is an entity in it's own right that sits on top of the OS, but the interface that allows us to interact with that structure (the application) is programmed in a common language? like the relationship between HTML and ASP.NET?

Comment: @DylanJackson I think you got it. Of course there are many variants,  hybrids and exceptions in practice, but the most common situation is what you stated.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Well that was harder than I thought it was going to be :) out of interest, kknowing what I was trying to ask, how would you, or someone with the correct vocabulary have worded the question?

Comment: @DylanJackson How about: *What are the advantages of using DBMS instead of trying to manage data myself?* Then in the body of the question, also mention that you are not familiar with the concept of DBMS and would like to know what are major components of a typical DBMS and how can one access a DBMS from a general-purpose language...

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I have my answer but I still havent' made myself clear. That just shows how much I have to learn in terms of, well, terms of reference. My question is purely to help me understand where DBMS like oracle actualy sit in terms of 'Programming Level' (as in (purely for arguments sake) binary is 1 c# is 10) I have good foundation training in using Oracle through SQL and SQL server via .net (including ASP)BUT I  was interested in the underlying ENGINE and it's RELATIONSHIP to programming frameworks.

Comment: @DylanJackson Relationship between engine and programming frameworks is implementation detail. It might be a network protocol, shared memory or even direct in-process calls and it may or may not be documented or stable between versions. Here is one example: *C# -> ADO.NET -> ODP.NET -> OCI -> TCP/IP -> Oracle process -> filesystem*. Here is another: *C# -> ADO.NET -> MS SQL Server Compact Data Provider -> MS SQL Server Compact DLL -> filesystem*.